# How can I emit an event passing the emitter inside a function in Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular, eventemitter, emit

Component PARENT (template):

```
<CHILD></CHILD>
<overlayer *ngIf="showPopup" (evTogglePopup)="onShowPopup($event)"></overlayer>
```

Component CHILD (@Component):

```
@Output() evTogglePopup = new EventEmitter();
...
this.inputUt.ajaxCheckExistingEmail(email, this.evTogglePopup);
```

a funtion of MyInputUtility (a provider @Injectable imported and used into CHILD):

```
ajaxCheckExistingEmail(email, evEmitter:EventEmitter<any>){
        if (email.valid){
            return this.http.post(
                GLOBAL_CONST.apiPath + "/user/user/api-check-user-email",
                'email=' + email.value,
                {headers: this.headers}
            ).map(response => response.json())
            .subscribe(val => {
                console.log(val);
                if( val.emailExists ){
                    evEmitter.emit(true);
                }
            });
        }
}
```

This "solution" doesn't work, and I was wondering if it's because evEmitter is passed by copy to the ajaxCheckExistingEmail function.

**Sosterd by myself**
The problem was that "overlayer" is a different selector form that one pointed by CHILD (selector), and I thought it would have worked as well.

I changed like this below and now it works:

```
<CHILD (evTogglePopup)="onShowPopup($event)"></CHILD>
    <overlayer *ngIf="showPopup"></overlayer>
```

Comment: `evTogglePopup` is an object and an object isn't passed by copy but by reference. What doesn't work? How does it not work?

Comment: Simply the event hasn't been emitting after/with "evEmitter.emit(true)" in the component that contain the event listener

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: Child is `<overlayer>`? Where is `this.inputUt.ajaxCheckExistingEmail(email, this.evTogglePopup);` being called from?

Comment: updated again, it should be clear...

Comment: I think you need to provide more code. A Plunker to reproduce would be great.

Comment: Ok, the problem was that "<overlayer>" is a different selector form the CHILD selector, and I thought it would have worked as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events from `@Output()` don't bubble. Either you pass it along from one parent to the next or you can use a shared service to share data between elements that are not in a direct parent-child relationship.

See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html for details.